# Transferring boot partition from Disk 1 to Disk 2?

Tags: windows, bootloader

I got a new laptop, and it came with a 750GB hard drive (unformatted) that was painfully slow. I got a 180GB SSD and put it into the second bay, and installed Windows 8 to the SSD.

The installer let me install to the second hard drive (SSD), but made a small (200MB?) partition on the first (slow 750) for the boot loader.

If I take the 750 out of the computer, it won't boot, even though there's a perfectly functional Windows 8 installation on the SSD.

Is there a way I can transfer the boot information to the SSD?

Comment: How much free space do you have on the SSD?

Comment: About 110 GB right now.

Answer (score 2):

Just boot from the install disk, pick the advance options to get to a command prompt and then fixmbr. [Here is one of the many available pages, describing step by step instruction](http://windows8themes.org/repair-fix-mbr-in-windows-8-using-the-command-prompt.html)s. Google "fix windows 8 boot loader" for more/others.